# Scrape tables from Wikipedia using python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape table data from this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Nepal
I've tried using pandas **pd.read_html** syntax but it doesn't work for the table I'm trying to scrape
(Confirmed COVID-19 cases in Nepal by district).

I tried using Beautifulsoup and pandas to scrape the data, but it doesn't work

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Nepal'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})
dfs=pd.read_html(table)
dfs[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Nepal'
# dfs = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Nepal", flavor="lxml")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})
dfs = pd.read_html(str(table).replace("2;", "2"))
print(dfs[0])
```

This works, you need to convert the table to a string for `read_html` to function properly.

For some reason the `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes show up as `"2;"` and I can't find a nice way to fix it - `pd.read_html()` doesn't like that so I just use `.replace()`.

In theory this should accomplish the same thing but shorter and easier, but it has the same issue with `rowspan`:

```
dfs = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_coronavirus_pandemic_in_Nepal", flavor="lxml")
print(dfs[0])  # whatever the index of the table is
```

It seems like this is a possible bug with `read_html` (pandas version 1.0.3).